# What's the purpose of controllers in Yii despite of handling user requests?

Tags: model-view-controller, yii, yii2

Having experience with some CMS and their frameworks I'm baffled by Yii's structure. Is there any usage of controllers in addition to responding to a user request? It's seems like they fill only the `$content` of some main layout and that's all.

Answer (score 0):

### Yii1

A controller is an instance of CController or of a class that extends CController. It is created by the application object when the user requests it. When a controller runs, it performs the requested action, which usually brings in the needed models and renders an appropriate view. An action, in its simplest form, is just a controller class method whose name starts with action.

[More Detail about Yii1 Controller](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.controller)

### Yii2

Controllers are part of the MVC architecture. They are objects of classes extending from yii\base\Controller and are responsible for processing requests and generating responses. In particular, after taking over the control from applications, controllers will analyze incoming request data, pass them to models, inject model results into views, and finally generate outgoing responses.

[More Detail about Yii2 Controller](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-controllers.html)

Comment: I understand that. Is there ANY other purposes except request handling? In some CMS and frameworks controllers are used much like widgets.